# How can I calculate combinations with additional constraints?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have a selection of items of type a, b and c.

I want to choose m from a random set of n of these items - e.g. 10 from 15.

However, I have additional constraints, namely:

1) There must be between 3 and 5 "a" items.
2) There must be between 3 and 5 "b" items.
3) There must be between 1 and 3 "c" items.

At present, I'm just calculating the standard 15C10 combinations and then filtering the list to get the final set.

Is there a more efficient approach?

Comment: Is the "random set of $n$ items" chosen first, then you want the number of combinations of size $m$ satisfying 1), 2), 3)? If so this will depend on exactly how many each of $a,b,c$ happen to be in the random set of $n$ things which gets chosen.

Comment: Yes. That is correct. n items is selected and then combinations with constraints need to be calculated on that. The selection of the items isn't totally random---in most causes there will be enough of each item to meet the minimum constraints. In the few erroneous cases where that constraint isn't met, it's a trivial check to return the empty set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, we can simply list the possibilities:

\begin{array}{c c c}
a & b & c\\ \hline
5 & 4 & 1\\
5 & 3 & 2\\
4 & 5 & 1\\
4 & 4 & 2\\
4 & 3 & 3\\
3 & 5 & 2\\
3 & 4 & 4
\end{array}
so there are a total of seven solutions.

Here is a more general approach:

Let $a$ denote the number of items of type $a$ that are selected; let $b$ denote the number of items of type $b$ that are selected; let $c$ denote the number of items of type $c$ that are selected.  Then 
$$a + b + c = 10 \tag{1}$$
which is an equation in the positive integers subject to the constraints $3 \leq a \leq 5$, $3 \leq b \leq 5$, and $1 \leq c \leq 3$.

Let $a' = a - 2$; let $b' = b - 2$.  Then $1 \leq a' \leq 3$, $1 \leq b' \leq 3$, and $1 \leq c \leq 3$.  Substituting $a' + 2$ for $a$ and $b' + 2$ for $b$ in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
a' + 2 + b' + 2 + c & = 10\\
a' + b' + c & = 6 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
which is an equation in the positive integers subject to the constraints that $a', b', c \leq 3$.  Without those constraints, a particular solution of equation 2 corresponds to the placement of two addition signs in the five spaces between successive ones in a row of six ones.  For instance, 
$$1 1 + 1 1 + 11$$
corresponds to the solution $a' = 2$, $b' = 2$, $c' = 2$ of equation 2 and $a = 4$, $b = 4$, and $c = 2$ of equation 1, while 
$$1 1 1 + 1 1 + 1$$
corresponds to the solution $a' = 3$, $b' = 2$, $c' = 1$ of equation 2 and $a = 5$, $b = 4$, and $c = 1$ of equation 1.  Hence, the number of solutions of equation 2 in the positive integers is 
$$\binom{5}{2} = 10$$
since we must choose which two of the five spaces between successive ones in a row of six ones will be filled with addition signs.

However, we have counted solutions in which one of the variables exceeds $3$.  We need to exclude them.

Suppose $a' > 3$.  Let $a'' = a' - 3$. Then $a''$ is a positive integer.  Substituting $a'' + 3$ for $a'$ in equation 2 yields 
\begin{align*}
a'' + 3 + b' + c & = 6\\
a'' + b' + c & = 3 \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Equation 3 is an equation in the positive integers.  There is just one such solution, namely $(1, 1, 1)$.  By symmetry, there is also one solution in which $b' > 3$ and one solution in which $c' > 3$.  Hence, the number of solutions of equation 1 that satisfy the constraints is 
$$\binom{5}{2} - 3 = 7$$
as we found by listing them.